# Camel K Rest route needs JSON marshalling and commented code executed

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, apache-camel-k, camel-rest

### A - Case 1: Rest DSL Example fails

I'm trying to apply the example written in the [Apache Camel Rest DSL component](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/rest-dsl.html#_rest_dsl_with_java). The simplified version of the same example for **Camel K** can be seen as below;

```java
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class RestRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        // rest endpoints
        rest("/status")
            .get("/hello").to("direct:hello");
        
        // routes
        from("direct:hello")
            .transform().constant("Hello World");
        
    }

}
```

And then, the build fails as below;

```
levent.divilioglu:camel-k-ex $ kamel run RestRoute.java --dev
integration "rest-route" created
Progress: integration "rest-route" in phase Initialization
Condition "IntegrationPlatformAvailable" is "True" for Integration rest-route: default/camel-k
Progress: integration "rest-route" in phase Building Kit
Integration rest-route in phase "Initialization"
Condition "IntegrationPlatformAvailable" is "True" for Integration rest-route: default/camel-k
Integration rest-route in phase "Building Kit"
Condition "IntegrationKitAvailable" is "False" for Integration rest-route: creating a new integration kit
Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Integration Kit) changed phase to "Build Submitted"
Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Scheduling"
Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Pending"
Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Running"
Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Integration Kit) changed phase to "Build Running"
Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Failed"
Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Initialization" (recovery 1 of 5)
Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Scheduling" (recovery 1 of 5)
Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Pending" (recovery 1 of 5)
Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Running" (recovery 1 of 5)
Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Failed" (recovery 1 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Initialization" (recovery 2 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Scheduling" (recovery 2 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Pending" (recovery 2 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Running" (recovery 2 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Failed" (recovery 2 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Initialization" (recovery 3 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Scheduling" (recovery 3 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Pending" (recovery 3 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Running" (recovery 3 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Failed" (recovery 3 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Initialization" (recovery 4 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Scheduling" (recovery 4 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Pending" (recovery 4 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Running" (recovery 4 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Failed" (recovery 4 of 5)
(combined from similar events): Integration rest-route subresource kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0 (Build) changed phase to "Initialization" (recovery 5 of 5)
Progress: integration "rest-route" in phase Error
Error: integration "rest-route" deployment failed
```

After I the log stops, I see it hangs on as can be seen below;

```
levent.divilioglu:camel-k-ex $ kamel get
NAME        PHASE   KIT
rest-route  Error   default/kit-c2o28iiqfl2hcn198ng0
```

### B - Case 2: Rest DSL Example works if Json Marshalling added

Then I delete by applying `kamel delete rest-route`, and then add just one lone, `marshal().json` to the end of the direct route, start it with `kamel run RestRoute.java --dev` and it works;

```java
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class RestRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        // rest endpoints
        rest("/status")
            .get("/hello").to("direct:hello");
        
        // routes
        from("direct:hello")
            .transform().constant("Hello World")
            .marshal().json();
        
    }

}
```

### C - Case 3: Route works with commented Json Marshalling

The most interesting and weird behaviour is this case. I comment out the `marshal().json()` line, and it continues to work. However even if I remove this commented line, it won't work. So the working example as follows;

```java
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class RestRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        // rest endpoints
        rest("/status")
            .get("/hello").to("direct:hello");
        
        // routes
        from("direct:hello")
            .transform().constant("Hello World");
            //.marshal().json()
        
    }

}
```

### D - Versions

MiniKube version;

```
minikube version: v1.17.1
commit: 043bdca07e54ab6e4fc0457e3064048f34133d7e
```

Apache Camel K version;

```
Apache Camel K Runtime 1.7.0
```

Camel K client version;

```
Camel K Client 1.4.0
```

### E - Findings and Questions

Where did I do wrong? I've just used the given example from the official apache website. Interesting things are;

- The example doesn't work itself, but any rest route, needs a JSON marshalling, even if the content is a simple text.
- The commented line seem to be executed in the integration file;

```
//.marshal().json()
```

Is this a bug, or is there a problem in the official [Apache Camel Rest DSL example](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/rest-dsl.html#_rest_dsl_with_java)?

Comment: can you include the logs of the operator ?

Comment: @LucaBurgazzoli Operator logs are not small, it is huge and hard to format in a small SO question. And is it needed here? I mean this is a function wise question. But Maybe it's better to add the logs to the github because I've already opened an issue, I suspect that this is a bug;

I'll add the logs there if you ask in the issue link;

https://github.com/apache/camel-k/issues/2341

Comment: it smells like a bug but it is probably about how the operator creates the container and the deployment so having some logs could help. Please add them (or an extract) to the github issue

Comment: @LucaBurgazzoli I've just added the Terminal Output and the Camel K Operator logs to the issue, check link: https://github.com/apache/camel-k/issues/2341#issuecomment-850205329